# How to auto populate a foreign table?

Tags: mysql

This problem has been bothering me for some time now and honestly i feel like i just don't know how to solve it.I have been trying to solve it for over a week or probably two . It's pretty simple but somehow it's just not working i don't know what I am doing wrong.

I have two tables one for user and one for messages.

table **user**

```
user_id

username  

password
```

---

table **messages**

```
user id       

id(fk) --- this column connects to the user_id in the parent table

message
```

---

So i am using `mysql` and `phpmyadmin`. when i type it in explicitly like this

```
INSERT INTO infoo ( `id`, `username`) VALUES ( '13', 'a;al;dld;ldladda');
```

it's inserted but what i when i do this

```
INSERT INTO infoo(id,username) VALUES((SELECT id FROM userinfo WHERE username = '$this->username' FROM userinfo),'$this->username')
```

The table is not being populated because i want the user to enter a message  and when the message is being inserted the primary key for the  user_id is automatically inserted into the foreign key column id for that specific user.

So please help me guys on this one, it seems pretty simple but sometimes the simple things comes with a lot of complexity.

Comment: If you are just entering a query, what do you expect `'$this->username'` to be?  There is no `$this` object in SQL.  I assume you must be talking about a programming language, which you haven't mentioned, and you also have not mentioned the error message you should be seeing, something like *"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM userinfo'"*